# Sufficient statistic for the density $f(x\mid\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}$

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, statistical-inference

I'm wondering if this density has a sufficient statistic to summarize an independent and identically distributed sample of random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ of this density.

The density is:

$$f(x\mid\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}I_{\mathbb{R}}(x)$$

After some computation, arrived to:

$$f(\textbf{x}\mid\theta)=e^{n\theta-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}e^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-e^{-(x_i-\theta)})}I_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\textbf{x})$$

But with this expression, it seems impossible to resume the information in a statistic because of the exponent of the middle factor. There, the $x_i$'s will allways be separated, but together (each one) with the parameter ($\theta$). So it will be impossible to factorize this expression (to use the Halmos Factorization Theorem), meaning that there is no sufficient statistic. Am I concluding correctly, or  i'm missing something?

Comment: This is a [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f(\textbf{x}|\theta)=e^{n\theta-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}e^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-e^{-(x_i-\theta)})}I_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\textbf{x}) = e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}\cdot e^{n\theta-e^\theta\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-x_i}}=h(x)g\left(\theta,\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-x_i}\right)
$$
By Neyman-Fisher factorization theorem, $T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-x_i}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.